# Inheritance and operator overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Hi I am new to c++ and had some conceptual questions that I wasn't able to find any direct answers to online.
So if we have a parent class and multiple children classes and we want to create an overloaded input function for it. So do we create it for every child class or just for once for the parent class. Also do we have to define the function in every class even if we leave it blank?
For example:

```
class A{
public:
   friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &, A &);
   friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const A &);
}

class B: public A{

}

class C: public A{

}
```

So would the above be correct and using this implementation I can take input of both B and C?

What would be the correct method if I had to implement another operator like + that has different implementations for class B and C. Do I just define them individually (because I read that friend functions cannot be inherited, i might be wrong)

Comment: You will need to overload `operator>>` and `operator<<` in each child class.  You can't make the operators virtual.

Comment: You cannot make operators virtual, but you can have an operator call virtual functions. So the operator can be a one liner, with all the actual work done in the virtual function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so even if the input and output code is exactly the same for both B and C I still have to define it individually in those?

Comment: No you don't, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Or I could offer one on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kDMep9Fps4GALNMS) :) Oh.  Yours is not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what @john said, basically, something like this (reduced to a minimal example):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const A &a);

private:
    virtual std::ostream& print (std::ostream &os) const { std::cout << m_x; return os; }
    int m_x = 42;
};

class B: public A {
    std::ostream& print (std::ostream &os) const override { std::cout << m_y; return os; }
    int m_y = 84;
};

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const A &a) { return a.print (os); }

int main ()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

Note that you don't have to override `print` in any particular derived class if you don't want to.  It's just a virtual function like any other.